# My product show up in wrong positions

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

6 weeks ago i updated my M1 to M2.2.3, 2 weeks ago i updated tot 2.2.5

After i updated to M2.2.5 my (old) products, on my productpage (like woman), show up in the wrong order. The oldest products show up as first, and the newest at last.

The products who are on top, came from my M1 store.

I did'nt give them a number for the position.
And in "products in catagorie" the products are in the right position. 
[image]

I even did'nt change anything at " Default Product Listing Sort By" it's at position.
[image]
[image]

Someone now whats wrong? Do need to change something that it will be oke again?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
    <referenceBlock name="product_list">
     <action method="setSortBy">
   <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
 </action>
   <action method="setDefaultDirection">
   <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
   </action>
   </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: I did doubleclick > save > reindex + clear cache.
Still display in wrong order.

Did i forgot something to change?

Maybe insert a xml code? What is showing newest first? Just a suggestion.

Comment: Is saw this code for M1 does it works for M2? And so yes, what do i need to paste between <dir>desc</dir>.

<reference name="product_list">
<action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
</reference>

Comment: @Joost i have edited my answer please check it may  help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i get the following error:

Element 'referenceBlock': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move, head, body ). Line: 1

Comment: I tested it twice, but it doesn't work at the moment.

Comment: please replace referenceBlock with referenceContainer and try

Comment: Get a new error: Element 'action': This element is not expected. Line: 2

Comment: Got any idea for this?

Comment: Anyone who can help me out?